# How to save command line log to text file?

Tags: command-line

I have several .cmd files that I run one after the other.  These can be several thousand lines of text.  I would like to save the output to a text file, but I can't figure out how.  I've tried the > and >> operators, but nothing is generated in the text files.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If the programs are sending their output to stderr you would need to redirect stderr to stdout in order to capture it in your log file.. ie

```
cmd >> cmd.log 2>&1
```